# How to refactor in Intellij - method with parameters to class with fields

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

Given a method

```
public class SomeClass{ 
    public void methodName (Param1 param1, Param2 param2, Param3 param){
        ...
    }
}
```

called as

```
SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass();
someObject.methodName(x, y, z);
```

What's the fastest way to refactor `someObject.methodName(x, y, z);` in IntelliJ to

```
public class MethodNameHandler{
    private Param1 param1;
    private Param2 param2;
    private Param3 param3;

    public MethodNameHandler(Param1 param1, Param2 param2, Param3 param3){
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
        this.param3 = param3;
    }

    public void methodName(){
            ...
    }
}
```

called as

```
new MethodNamehandler(x, y, z).methodName();
```

Comment: is your original method static or on some object?

Comment: @Jaroslaw The original method is on some object.

Comment: Then this is a compilation error: `methodName(x, y, z);`. Could you please update your question and show how it actually looks now?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I have updated my answer. In short, in step 2 instead of doing "convert to instance method" we just select "move" to move it from one class to another.

Comment: You can also use F6 (move) as step 2 which is even shorter... Thanks.

Comment: If there is any better way for step 3, I'd like to know it too :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IntelliJ 14.1.4 and 15.0:

### Step 1:

Place a caret on the method declaration, press `ctrl + alt + shift + t` (or `cmd` instead of `ctrl` if on Mac) and select `7. Parameter Object...`. Type in a name (I used `Holder`) for a new class and press `Refactor`.

The popup will ask you for default value for `Holder`, leave `Leave blank` so the compiler will tell you if anything went wrong. In this case, no default value is needed so it should be refactored correctly without any compiler errors.

### Step 2:

Again place a caret on the edited method, `ctrl/cmd + alt + shift + t`, select `4. Move...`. The `Holder` class should be available and selected. Press `Refactor`.

### Step 3:

Finally, in your `Holder` class inline getters generated in the first step. Place a caret on getter declaration and press `ctrl/cmd + alt + n`. Unfortunately, it has to be done separately for each of them.